# Heroku + browserify-rails: Error: Cannot find module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, reactjs, browserify

While deploying to Heroku, I got "Error: Cannot find module" error.

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "== README",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "somerepo.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^11.0.1",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.0.1",
    "object-assign": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.4.1",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "superagent": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

This is the log when I run "git push heroku master"

```
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── browserify@11.0.1
remote:        ├── browserify-incremental@3.0.1
remote:        ├── object-assign@3.0.0
remote:        ├── react@0.13.3
remote:        ├── react-image-gallery@0.4.1
remote:        ├── reactify@1.1.1
remote:        └── superagent@1.3.0
```

After that I got this error.

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        AssetSync: using /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
remote:        [DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
remote:        I, [2015-08-08T08:09:07.998223 #595]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/public/assets/app.js-a57be479852c067f49ad0f930156917fbc753d782ac615de774d5f037964dcfe.jsx
remote:        Browserify: /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/.bin/browserify -t reactify --extension=".js.jsx, .react.jsx, .jsx" -r react --list -o "/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/output20150808-595-41bgqb" -
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        BrowserifyRails::BrowserifyError: Error while running `/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/.bin/browserify -t reactify --extension=".js.jsx, .react.jsx, .jsx" -r react --list -o "/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/    output20150808-595-41bgqb" -`:
remote:        events.js:85
remote:        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
remote:        ^
remote:        Error: Cannot find module 'react-image-gallery' from '/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/app/assets/javascripts/components'
remote:        at /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
remote:        at process (/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
remote:        at ondir (/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
remote:        at load (/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
remote:        at onex (/tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
remote:        at /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
remote:        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/browserify-rails-1.2.0/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:177:in `run_browserify'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/browserify-rails-1.2.0/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:113:in `dependencies'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/browserify-rails-1.2.0/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:90:in `commonjs_module?'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/browserify-rails-1.2.0/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:70:in `should_browserify?'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/browserify-rails-1.2.0/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:23:in `evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_65611fbfcf2cb3d9c9e2addc22015359/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

// app/assets/javascripts/components/ImageSlider.js.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ImageGallery = require('react-image-gallery');
var request = require('superagent');

var ImageSlider = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      tourImages: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(currentPath);
    var tempArray = currentPath.split('/');
    var tourId = parseInt(tempArray[tempArray.length-1]);
    this._fetchImages(tourId);
  },

  _fetchImages: function(tourId) {
    var _this = this;
    request
      .get('some_end_point/' + tourId + '/fetch_images')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (res.ok) {
          _this.setState({
            tourImages: res.body.tourImages
          })
          console.log(_this.state.tourImages);
        }
      })
  },

  render: function () {
    var tourImages = this.state.tourImages;
    var tourImageList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= tourImages.length - 1; i++) {
      tourImageList.push({original: tourImages[i].tour_photo.large.url, thumbnail: tourImages[i].tour_photo.small.url})
    }
    var options = {
      items: tourImageList
    };
    return (
      <ImageGallery {...options} />
    );
  }
});

module.exports = ImageSlider
```

From the log, I can find out the line below has some problem.

```
var ImageGallery = require('react-image-gallery');
```

But I don't know why it causes an error. 
Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem, so after all I deploy to AWS. I needed to do "npm install --save react-image-gallery" after "npm install", and I cannot do it on Heroku.

Comment: I'm having similar issue. I just died inside a little...:(

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error while trying to run an `npm run compile` with Browserify and react.

It was not able to recognize my react gem even after doing an `npm install`.

What I did was:

```
rm -rf node_modules #to clean out stale node modules, and then
npm update
```